# Highlight Auto-copy with TouchPad on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

In Ubuntu 10.04, how do I highlight something and it will be copied automatically to the clipboard?

With my laptop, I have to highlight a text, then right-click on it and click copy... Is there a shortcut for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Fire Fox pretty easy with the [AutoCopy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/383/) add-on, but I do not know of a way to auto copy system wide.